# Tired of guessing - cannot get line break to work

Tags: php

VERY simple routine that pulls the name of each PDF file in a folder and creates a list of each file found with a link to it.   But I cannot get a line break between the items

Nothing seems to give me each file name and link on a new line.  I have no idea why.

Neither of the \n has any affect at all.

```
    <?php
$directory = "./images/";
$phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.pdf");


foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
echo "\n","<a href=$phpfile>".basename($phpfile)."</a>";
echo "\n";
}
?>
```

All I get for output is this....all on one line.

```
CAD_REPEQUEST.pdf JP_CADS.pdf JP_Reports.pdf
```

What I want is this....

```
CAD_REPEQUEST.pdf
JP_CADS.pdf
JP_Reports.pdf
```

Comment: It seems typo, remove comma from first echo statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're outputting to a Web page you'll need to replace `\n` with `<br>`.

If you're outputting to a text or other type of file, you may wish to replace `\n` with the constant `PHP_EOL`.

If you're outputting this to an email that's getting sent in text format, you'll have trouble with some clients, like Outlook, that will automatically attempt to remove unnecessary line breaks. Sometimes using a double line break helps, or you could convert your email to HTML and use the `<br>` approach.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks Lawrence.  I will accept your answer as soon as the timer allows.